# When to use a View over a ViewControlller

Tags: swift, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I would like to know what the best practices are when deciding a class must be a UIview or UIviewcontroller.

I'm working on an app that has multiple classes and views used at once in a single Viewcontroller. I have a view that dynamically creates buttons. This view lives alongside many other views in the ViewController. Since this view implements quite a few lines of codeI made it onto a separate class. The question then is: should it extend a UiView or a UIViewcontroller?

This view will have a few properties such as padding, available dimensions etc. These depend on autolayout anchors of it's parent Viewcontroller it's a subclass of. If I use a UIview these will not be instantiated on Init.

why, should I choose one over the other?

class TagController : UIView {

```
override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}


var buttons : [UIButton: String]?

var sidePadding = CGFloat(15);
var topPadding = CGFloat(15);
var spacing = CGFloat(10);

var availableHeight : CGFloat!
var availableWidth :  CGFloat!

func createButton (title: String) -> UIButton {
    let maxWidth : CGFloat = 180;
    let button = UIButton();

    button.setTitle(title, for: .normal)
    button.titleLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "Avenir-Light", size: 15.0)
    button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false;
    self.addSubview(button)
    button.frame = CGRect(x:0,y:0,width:button.intrinsicContentSize.width, height: button.intrinsicContentSize.height)
    if button.frame.width > maxWidth { button.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: maxWidth).isActive = true }
    button.backgroundColor = .blue
   // button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.onButtonPresed(_:)), for: .touchUpInside);
    return button;
}


public func addButton(name: String) {
    let button = createButton(title: name)
    setConstriants(button: button)
}

private func setConstriants(button: UIButton) {

        for label in buttons {

        if totalHeight + 50 > availableHeight { createMoreButton(topPadding); break };

        let button = createButton(buttonText: label)
        let buttonWidth = button.intrinsicContentSize.width;
        let buttonHeight = button.intrinsicContentSize.height;

        if buttonWidth > availableWidth {
            button.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant:  availableWidth  - sidePadding).isActive = true;
        }
        if rowLength == 0 && rowCount == 0
        {
            setFirstButtonConstraint(button: button, totalHeight: totalHeight, sidePadding: sidePadding)
            rowLength += buttonWidth + sidePadding // FIX annoying first row image overlap

        }
        else if rowLength + buttonWidth + padding < availableWidth
        {
            setConstraint(button: button, lastButton: lastButton, totalHeight: totalHeight, padding: padding)
            rowLength += buttonWidth + padding;
        }
        else
        {

            totalHeight += buttonHeight + padding
            rowLength = buttonWidth + sidePadding;
            rowCount += 1;
            setNewRowConstraint(button: button, totalHeight:totalHeight , sidePadding: sidePadding)
        }
        indexOfLastButton += 1;
        lastButton = button
        displayedButtons.append(button)
        print("Buttons displayed   \(displayedButtons.count)")
    }

    pulsate_buttons(duration: 0.1)
}

private func removeDisplayedButtons() {
    for _ in 0...displayedButtons.count {
        displayedButtons.popLast()?.removeFromSuperview();
    }
};

private func setFirstButtonConstraint(button: UIButton, totalHeight: CGFloat, sidePadding: CGFloat) {
    button.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.topAnchor, constant: totalHeight).isActive = true;
    button.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.leadingAnchor, constant: sidePadding + 5).isActive = true;
}
private func setConstraint(button: UIButton, lastButton: UIButton, totalHeight: CGFloat, padding:CGFloat) {
    button.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: lastButton.trailingAnchor, constant: padding).isActive = true;
    button.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.topAnchor, constant: totalHeight).isActive = true;
}
private func setNewRowConstraint(button: UIButton, totalHeight: CGFloat, sidePadding: CGFloat) {
    button.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.leadingAnchor, constant: sidePadding).isActive = true;
    button.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.topAnchor, constant: totalHeight).isActive = true;
}

private func createMoreButton(_ topPadding: CGFloat) {
    if moreButton != nil { return }
    let btn = UIButton()
    btn.setImage(UIImage(named: "suggestionCloud_more_button.png"), for: .normal)
    let buttonText = "Moooar.."
    btn.setTitle(buttonText, for: .normal)
    btn.setTitleColor(.black, for: .normal)
    btn.titleLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "Avenir-Light", size: 15.0)
    self.addSubview(btn)
    moreButton = btn
    btn.frame = CGRect(x: (self.frame.size.width/2 - 20), y: self.frame.size.height * 0.85, width: 40, height: 15)
    btn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(showMoreButtons(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
}

@objc func showMoreButtons(_: UIButton) {
    pulsate_view(duration: 0.1)
    if indexOfLastButton == labelStore.count { indexOfLastButton = 0; return createLayout(buttons : labelStore)}
    let buttonsToBeDisplayed : [String] = Array(labelStore[indexOfLastButton...])
    createLayout(buttons: buttonsToBeDisplayed)
}
```

Comment: First of all, your view can be probably greatly simplified using a `UITableView` or `UIStackView`.
It seems to me that mostly it is "view" code but it has some parts that are more "controller" code (e.g. `showMoreButtons` which handles user actions). More likely you should split that into a view and into a controller that uses that view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I like to think of it this way: a `UIView` hosts and manages discrete content while a `UIViewController` hosts and manages application content that is composed of many pieces of discrete content.

You can think of it in terms of desktop applications where a "window" is a `UIViewController`, while the elements of this window (buttons, toolbars, etc.) are `UIViews` (you can also host other `UIViewControllers` inside of a `UIViewController`).

In general, `UIViews` should not decide on application navigation logic but should defer that to the `UIViewController`.

In simple terms, if something is presented modally or takes up the whole screen, it probably is meant to be a `UIViewController`.

Traditionally, Apple adopts an MVC paradigm (Model/View/Controller). Where your content is a Model (a person's date of birth, a photo you've taken), the View is where it is displayed and the Controller mediating between the content management (persistence, retrieval) and the display of the content.

BTW: Look into `UIStackView` for your button rows.

---

**Bonus**: How to have a custom initializer for a programatically instantiated `UIView`.

If your view is only every created programatically (and not instantiated through interface builder), you can define a required initializer for it as such:

```
class MyView: UIView {
    var required: Bool
    var anotherRequiredVar: String

    required init(frame: CGRect, something: Bool, somethingElse: String) {
        required = something
        anotherRequiredVar = somethingElse
        super.init(frame: frame)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init with coder not implemented")
    }
}
```

In this example, the init?(coder) method throws an exception. This initializer is run by interface builder when unarchiving your Storyboard or Nib contents. Since you won't be needing it, you can just throw a fatalError (since that method needs to be implemented for compilation to succeed).

Comment: Thanks! So in the case of a modally presented View such as a dyanmic collection of buttons which get handles in that class would be a candidate for both options, however since no navigation is handled here a UIView would suffice?

Comment: I think your dynamic collection of buttons fits more my idea of a UIView than that of a UIViewController.

Comment: Thanks! One last question: How should I handle UIview class properties that are dependent on the viewController's properties?. I would like to set those as soon as the View gets initialized, but i'm not allowed to change overiide init() 's singature

Comment: If you are instantiating your `UIViews` automatically through Interface Builder (Storyboard or Nib), there is no easy way to do that. Possible solutions: 1- You can code defensively by having these variables default to something. 2- You can use `awakeFromNib` to set defaults up for these variables. 3- You can have an initialization function (not init, your own instance function) to gather the required parameters.

Comment: Thanks! I'm setting everything up programmatically using autolayout. Indeed I went with the defensive approach. After my View has been loaded in Viewcontroller viewDidLoad() is set all contraints via setConstraints() called from viewDidLoad . It is an alright solution, though I really don't like how far apart the logic of wiring everything up is. I guess that is just how it is

Comment: If you're setting up everything programatically, then the whole game changes. You can have a custom initializer for your view. I'll update my answer with this.

Comment: Ooohh!! that makes me very happy! That really changes everything, thanks!